# Can't access string field of a SerializedProperty

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Found similar problems but none identical:

I have a class, "Action", which is a ScriptableObject.

```
[Serializable]
public class Action : ScriptableObject
{
    [SerializeField] public string ID = "";
    [SerializeField] public float defaultCost = 1f;
}
```

I want to maintain a ReorderableList in an editor window which allows me to easily create and remove instances of this ScriptableObject. I also want to be able to easily adjust the ID and defaultCost fields using text fields on this list. However, in order to do so, I need to be able to access these fields as subproperties of the SerializedProperty elements of the ReorderableList.

Apparently it should work like this: (taken from the method for custom drawing an element of the ReorderableList)

```
SerializedProperty element = reorderableList.serializedProperty.GetArrayElementAtIndex(index);

EditorGUI.PropertyField
(
    new Rect(x, y, width, height),
    element.FindPropertyRelative("ID"),
    GUIContent.none
);
```

However, element.FindPropertyRelative("ID") returns only null for both properties.

I know I have the element correct, because if I use

```
Action action = element.objectReferenceValue as Action;
```

I am able to correctly retrieve the action object.

So just to summarise, I need to find a way to get the fields of this ScriptableObject as SerializedProperties so I can edit them in a custom Editor Window.

Comment: It's because FindPropertyRelative tries to retrieve property, but your ID is field. You can change ID to property like `[SerializeField] public string ID {get;set;}` I'm not sure if SerializeField is valid attribute for property. Meybe attribute is not required for properties. You then need to populate property with default value in constructor like `this.ID = ""`

Comment: I tried changing my action class to look like `[Serializable]
public class Action : ScriptableObject
{
public string ID
{
    get { return m_id; }
    set { m_id = value; }
}

[SerializeField]
private string m_id = "";`, it doesn't seem to have worked.

Answer (score 1):

Found a terrible but fully functional solution.

Retrieve the object by getting its reference type, create a new SerializedObject, use FindProperty on that to get the property, and then apply changes.

```
SerializedObject ac = new SerializedObject(action);

EditorGUI.PropertyField
(
new Rect(x, y, width, height),
ac.FindProperty("ID"),
GUIContent.none
);

ac.ApplyModifiedProperties();
```